# 軸のラベルと目盛りがぶつかってしまう

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

以下の図を出力したときに、目盛りとラベルがぶつかってしまい、どのような対処をすればよろしいでしょうか？

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=(0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8)) #rect=(x0,y0,width,height)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x_list, t_list)
ax.set_xlabel("Position",fontsize=24)
ax.set_ylabel("Time",fontsize=24)
ax.set_zlabel("|φ|^2",fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlim(2*n,0)
ax.set_ylim(2*n,0)
ax.set_zlim(0,1)
offset = pp_map.ravel() + np.abs(pp_map.min())
fracs = offset.astype(float)/offset.max()
norm = colors.Normalize(fracs.min(), fracs.max())
clrs = cm.cool(norm(fracs))
ax.bar3d(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), pp_map.ravel() ,0.5, 0.5, -pp_map.ravel(),color =clrs)
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((0, 0, 0, 0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((0, 0, 0, 0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((0, 0, 0, 0))
ax.grid(color="white")
ax.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

ご指摘よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`set_xlabel`メソッド](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xlabel)の`labelpad`引数で軸から離す距離を指定できます。適宜調整ください。

```
ax.set_xlabel("Position", labelpad=10, fontsize=24)
ax.set_ylabel("Time", labelpad=20, fontsize=24)
ax.set_zlabel("|φ|^2", labelpad=10, fontsize=18)
```

Comment: 誠にありがとうございます！！！！

Comment: （できれば、質問には自己完結している実際に動くコードを書いていただけると助かります。[推測で復元](https://gist.github.com/yohhoy/e73bfb014c3664c6cf69c38c752aab40)するのは結構手間なので...）

Comment: 申し訳ないです！！次からそのようにします！